# How can I make the effect of a plane cutting a cone?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

Here is the sample image:

[image]

I want to make the effect that the plane is cutting through the cone. That is I want some part of the plane is at the back and some is at the front, how to do it beautifully and easilly using illustrator?

I just don't know how to make one part of the plane in the front layer and the the other part in the bottom layer.

Comment: Hi buzhidao, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Is the included image something you've created or is it an example of what you'd like to replicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to address the visibility of lines.

[image]